# Securely pass username and password info to Ajax php script

Tags: php, ajax, get, credentials

I have a PHP script that is used to return data to a web page via AJAX.  In the PHP script a connection to MySQL is made by the specific user logged into the website, the data is downloaded then returned to the web page.  For this purpose username and password info are passed to the script via $_GET variables (I know, very bad).  This was done in haste but now I want to fix this problem.  The obvious problem is that these credentials show up when the webpage page it loads.

What is the best (most secure) way of passing these variables to the PHP script? Encryption?

Am I going about this all wrong? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Encryption would be kind of useless here as JavaScript is client-side and not server side. A way to have it more secure is using SSL and don't handle the login via AJAX but POST without using AJAX.

Comment: where would be the diffrence, if he uses an ajax - post/get or an simple form post ?

Comment: he should use a regular form post, not AJAX to post the data.

Comment: yes you wrote that.. but i ask you why... where do you see a difference. as you said, if it is not send via an ssl connection its transmitted plain text. besides an ajax request can be post to. so i dont see a reason for not using ajax. post is post. plain text is plain text. so.. where do you see the difference.

Comment: If I use jQuery's post function, I will have something like this: `$.post("test.php", { username: "John", pass: "some_password" } );`.  This would also show up on the page.  I am not too familiar with SSL will have to research a little.  Thanks.

Comment: The difference is that he should use SSL and I (personal opinion) don't like sending login data via AJAX, that's why I would implement the login without AJAX. Also people with deactivated JavaScript would be able to login, too. Just a side effect, but it's a plus for my solution I guess...

Comment: Well the users are already logged into my site when they need to access this AJAX script.  The problem is the AJAX script doesn't know who they are, as it is standing alone, and does not have the authentication scripts above it.

Comment: If you can't switch that part to AJAXless post, at least use SSL to secure the connection between client and server.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean.  Before I would make the whole website without AJAX and I never ran into this problem, and I would use POST for some information, but better, the PHP script could access the website's user authentication module, so i wouldn't need to pass around username and password info.  I love that AJAX updates data in real time. I think there must be a better way to get these credentials into the ajax php script. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't feel like reworking it into POST (see Kaisers answer +1), you could pass some additional unique encrypted $_GET variables that would act like authentication before any data is actually processed or returned.